# Client can't reach action server

Tags: ros, action-server, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm launching two agents simultaneously, both of which create an action server, but only one makes a request (hardcoded that way). The problem is that while both processes seem to run fine on their own, the request from the client doesn't seem to reach the server. I don't understand what might be wrong. I'm putting below a snippet of code.

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, ...):
            ..............
            self.server = actionlib.SimpleActionServer(rospy.get_name(), doMeFavorAction, self.execute, False)
            self.server.start()

    def run():
        if self.ID == 1: #
            print 'I am asking for smth'
            self.test_action_server()

    def test_action_server(self):
        #the names of the agents are as follows /robot[ID]/brain_node
        client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('/robot2/brain_node', doMeFavorAction)
        client.wait_for_server()
        print rospy.get_name()
        print 'I am requesting a favor'
        goal = doMeFavorGoal(3500)
        print str(goal)
        # Fill in the goal here
        client.send_goal(goal)
        client.wait_for_result(rospy.Duration.from_sec(5.0))
        print client.get_result()

    def execute(self, goal):
        # Do lots of awesome groundbreaking robot stuff here
        print dishwasher_id

        time.sleep(100)
        percent = 0
        while percent < 100:
             percent = percent + 10
             print percent
             self.server.publish_feedback(percent)
        self.server.set_succeeded(48)
        time.sleep(100)
```

Any help is very much appreciated :).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248903/client-can%27t-reach-action-server/) by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2016-11-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-27**:
Could you please check and correct the indentation of your Python code? `def run()` and the code below seem to be at the same indent level at the moment, which is rather confusing.

**Comment by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) on 2016-11-27**:
Sorry about that, I fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After revising what I had written, I found many minor things that were wrong, so I rewrote in the following way, and now it works like a charm:

```
def __init__(self):
     ......
     self.server = actionlib.SimpleActionServer(rospy.get_name(), doMeFavorAction, self.execute, False)
     self.server.start()

def done(self, state, result):
    print state
    print result 

def active(self):
    print 'Goal just sent!'

def feedback(self, feedback):
    print 'Feedback: %f\n' % feedback.percent_complete

def test_action_server(self):
    client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('/robot2/brain_node', doMeFavorAction)
    client.wait_for_server()
    print rospy.get_name()
    print 'I am requesting a favor'
    goal = doMeFavorGoal(3500)
    print str(goal)
    print goal

        client.send_goal(goal, self.done, self.active, self.feedback)

def execute(self, goal):
    # Do lots of awesome groundbreaking robot stuff here
    print goal.dishwasher_id
    feedback = doMeFavorFeedback()
    result = doMeFavorResult()
    percent = 0
    while percent < 100.0:
        percent = percent + 10.0
        feedback.percent_complete = percent
        self.server.publish_feedback(feedback)
    result.total_dishes_cleaned = 30
    self.server.set_succeeded(result)
```

---

Originally posted by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) with karma: 176 on 2016-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0